# What is the equivalent in MySql for STATISTICS IO?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

When I do a query on MSSQL, I can issue these statements to get statistics on time and IO returned with the query.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
```

They are a good first look indicator for the performance of the query. Does something like this exist in MySql and how do I enable it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what `SET STATISTICS` does in MSSQL, but you are probably looking for the [`SHOW PROFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html) and `SHOW PROFILES` commands.

Answer (score 0):

From the `MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual`

> The SHOW PROFILE and SHOW PROFILES statements are deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future MySQL release. Use the Performance Schema
>   instead